# Flagment not showing UI when opened from Notification

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, fragment

I'm developing my first project and there's a fragment that shows the timer in the UI. And every 1 hour, the UI will notify the user and allow the user to navigate back to that timer flagment when he/she tab the Notification bar.

> The problem is when I tab the notification bar, the activity is called
>   and the TimerFlagment is opened but there's just white blank on the
>   screen, all the UI are gone.

Here is the method for issuing the Notification.

```
public void issueNotification(String action, String message){
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setAction(action);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_app)
                    .setContentTitle("My Application")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            this,
                            0,
                            resultIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    ));
    int mNotificationId = 001; // Sets an ID for the notification
    ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build()); 
    Log.w("TimerFragment","Issue Notification");
}
```

and this is the code in the MainActivity where I check that if the MainActivity is called from the notification or not.

```
try{
        String action = getIntent().getAction();
        if(action != null){
            if(action.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase("NAV_TO_TIMER")){
               // Log.w("MainActivity","Launch timer");
               if (fragmentList.get("timer") != null) {
                  Log.w("MainActivity", "TimerFragment is in memory");
                  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.frame_container, fragmentList.get("timer")).commit();
               }
            }
        } 
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Problem consuming action from intent", e);
    }
```

I'm really new for implementing Notification and the code I got are from this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#notify).

Thank you in advance, any answer at all are appreciated.

Comment: Does the Log statement in catch block appear in Logcat?

Comment: No, the code run without any exception and it goes to the innermost of the "IF" statement, but the TimerFragment is not created.